# Delete a Single Gmail contact using PHP

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

I'm using this script to delete contacts from GMAIL and sometimes it works but it won't delete every contact example, im trying to delete "ADRIANA CALI" this contact is on a group called "modelos", but it won't delete this name... any ideas please?

```
<?php

// load Zend Gdata libraries
//require 'init_autoloader.php';
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$user = "sampleeemail@gmail.com";
$pass = "samplepassword";
//contact name to delete
$contact_name = 'ADRIANA CALI';


try {
   $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cl');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
   echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}
try {       
  // perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cp');
  $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
  $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full');
  $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);

$contacts=array();;

foreach($feed as $entry){
    $name = (string) $entry->title;
    if(strcasecmp($name,$contact_name)==0) {
        //echo '<xmp>';print_r($entry);echo '</xmp>';
        $id = substr((string) $entry->id,(strpos((string) $entry->id,'base')+5));
        $contacts[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name); 
        echo $entry->id;
    }
    //$xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->getXML());

    //$obj = new stdClass;echo $entry->title."<br/>";
    //$obj->name = (string) $entry->title;
    //$editLink = $entry->getEditLink()->href;
    //echo $editLink.'-66<br>';
    //$extra_header = array('If-Match'=>'*'); 
    //$entry->delete();
}

  ?>
  <h2>Deleting One Contact</h2>
  <div><?php echo count($contacts); ?> contact(s) found for deletion under Contact "<?php echo $contact_name; ?>".</div>

  <?php


  foreach($contacts as $contact){
      $deleteLink = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/'.$contact['id'];

   //$deleteLink = ' http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/base/contactID';

   //echo $deleteLink.'<br>';
   //$deleteLink = $contact['id'];
   //$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cp');
    $client->setHeaders(array('If-Match'=>'*','If-None-Match'=>'anything'));
    $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
    $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);     
    // delete entry 
    $gdata->delete($deleteLink);


  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR 71:' . $e->getMessage());  
}
?>

<?php
// display results
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {       
?>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="name"><?php echo (!empty($contact['name'])) ? $contact['name'] : 'Name not available' . ' deleted!'; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: check this link http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-phpgooglecontact/ and this link http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/gdata-google-contacts-question-cant-update-contact-td3539863.html#. I think you shouldnot call set headers while deleting the entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because maximum contact was reached and query was not processing further, Now I have set the maximum limit to 1000

```
<?php

// load Zend Gdata libraries
//require 'init_autoloader.php';
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');

// set credentials for ClientLogin authentication
$user = "sampleemail@gmail.com";
$pass = "sample password";
//contact name to delete
$contact_name = 'ADRIANA CALI';


try {
   $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cl');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
   echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}
try {       
  // perform login and set protocol version to 3.0
  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cp');
  $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
  $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);

  $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000');
  $feed = $gdata->getFeed($query);

$contacts=array();;

foreach($feed as $entry){
    $name = (string) $entry->title;
    if(strcasecmp($name,$contact_name)==0) {
        //echo '<xmp>';print_r($entry);echo '</xmp>';
        $id = substr((string) $entry->id,(strpos((string) $entry->id,'base')+5));
        $contacts[] = array('id'=>$id,'name'=>$name); 
        //echo '<br>m-'.$name.'-'.$entry->id;
    }
    //$xml = simplexml_load_string($entry->getXML());

    //$obj = new stdClass;echo $entry->title."<br/>";
    //$obj->name = (string) $entry->title;
    //$editLink = $entry->getEditLink()->href;
    //echo $editLink.'-66<br>';
    //$extra_header = array('If-Match'=>'*'); 
    //$entry->delete();
}

  ?>
  <h2>Deleting One Contact</h2>
  <div><?php echo count($contacts); ?> contact(s) found for deletion under Contact "<?php echo $contact_name; ?>".</div>

  <?php


  foreach($contacts as $contact){
      $deleteLink = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/'.$contact['id'];

   //$deleteLink = ' http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/userEmail/base/contactID';

   //echo $deleteLink.'<br>';
   //$deleteLink = $contact['id'];
   //$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cp');
    $client->setHeaders(array('If-Match'=>'*','If-None-Match'=>'anything'));
    $gdata = new Zend_Gdata($client);
    $gdata->setMajorProtocolVersion(3);     
    // delete entry 
    $gdata->delete($deleteLink);


  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  die('ERROR 71:' . $e->getMessage());  
}
?>

<?php
// display results
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {       
?>
<div class="entry">
  <div class="name"><?php echo (!empty($contact['name'])) ? $contact['name'] : 'Name not available' . ' deleted!'; ?></div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```